# Rails 4: conditional update action working intermittently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my Rails 4 app, I have the following models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :metadatum
end

class Metadatum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Here is the schema of the Metadatum model:

```
create_table "metadata", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "post_id"
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "description"
  t.string   "host"
  t.string   "image"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.string   "link"
end
```

In the `create` action, I do the following to get data with the MetaInspector gem and store them in the `Metadatum` associated with the right `Post` record:

```
def create
    [...]
    if @post.format == "Link"
      @metadatum = @post.build_metadatum
      @link = MetaInspector.new(facebook_copy_link(@post.copy)) unless facebook_copy_link(@post.copy).blank?
      if @link
        @metadatum.title = @link.title
        @metadatum.description = @link.meta_tags["name"]["description"].to_s.tr('[""]', '')
        @metadatum.host = @link.host
        @metadatum.image = @link.images.best
        @metadatum.save
      end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        [...]
      end
    end
  end
```

Now, I need to implement a similar process in the edit action, taking into account that we have two cases:

1. The current Post `:format` was not set to "Link" prior to this `edit`, is now set to "Link", and therefore the `Metadatum` record associated with the `Post` is empty.
2. The current `Post` format was already set to "Link" prior to this `edit`, and we simply need to `update` the attributes of the `Metadatum` record associated with the `Post`.

Based on this reasoning, I have implemented the following in `Posts#Update`:

```
  def update
    [...]
      if @post.format == "Link"
        if @post.metadatum
          @metadatum = @post.metadatum
        else
          @metadatum = @post.build_metadatum
        end
        @link = MetaInspector.new(facebook_copy_link(@post.copy)) unless facebook_copy_link(@post.copy).blank?
        if @link
          @metadatum.update!(title: @link.title,
                            description: @link.meta_tags["name"]["description"].to_s.tr('[""]', ''),
                            host: @link.host,
                            image: @link.images.best)
        end
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        if @post.update(post_params)
          [...]
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

This only partially works and I can't understand why:

- let's say I have Link A saved in the post, change it to Link B and update the post, then nothing changes at all, neither in the console nor in the Posts show view.
- but, if I try and edit the same post again, keep Link B and update the post, then all right data appears, both in the console and in the Posts show view.

Any idea what is wrong here and how to fix it?